# Get the last value in multiple columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a dataset that I want to split columns and get only the row with the last non-empty string (from multiple columns). My initial table looks like this.

[image: Initial dataframe]

Now I split like this to have multiple columns.

```
df['name'].str.split(" ", expand = True)
```

And the result is the following.
[image: splitted data]

I would like to get the last NONE value. Here is the output I would like to have.

[image]

Comment: Friend advice - [Don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: did not post a question for a while here. I guess you are right. I could have pasted it.

Comment: no need `expand=True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by default arbitrary whitespace, so no parameter and then select last value of lists by slicing `[-1]`:

```
df['last'] = df['name'].str.split().str[-1]
```

Comment: Now, how easy was that? I missed that .str[-1]. I used instead df['last'] = df['name'].str.split()[-1] and got an Error. Thanks that does the job. lesson learnt.